# How to convert this example of nested ternary if-else to if-else loop

Tags: java, nested, ternary

How to convert this example of nested ternary constructor to if-else loop. I am an begginer and is complicated form me.

```
    int bill = 2000;
    int qty = 10;
    int days = 10;
    int discount = (bill > 1000)? (qty > 11)? 10 : days > 9? 20 : 30 : 5;
    System.out.println(discount);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do your homework yourself?

Comment: divide and conquer: start considering `days > 9? 20 : 30`

Comment: Thanks, I transformed this example. But is very tortuous.

Comment: Start at the inside and go outwards. This is straightforward, though persnickety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR:** See last code block for answer to question.*

---

First, an `if-else` statement is *not* a "loop".
`for`, `while`, and `do-while` are loops.
`if` is a conditional statement.

The operator precedence of the `? :` ternary conditional operator is so low you rarely need to use parentheses for the 3 parts, unless you have embedded assignment operators. E.g. `(bill > 1000) ? 30 : 5` is unnecessary, `bill > 1000 ? 30 : 5` means the same thing.

Also, for readability, always use spaces around operators.
`A? B : C` is wrong. It should be `A ? B : C`.

Now, since the ternary operator is right-associative, you don't need parenthesis when nesting, i.e.
`A ? B ? C : D : E` means `A ? (B ? C : D) : E`
`A ? B : C ? D : E` means `A ? B : (C ? D : E)`
The nested `? :` operator stays intact.

There is no need for the parenthesis, *however* keep this in mind. `A ? B : (C ? D : (E ? F : G))` is like an if-elseif-elseif-else statement, so the following are equivalent:

```java
// single line
x = A ? B : C ? D : E ? F : G;

// wrapped for readability, to show structure
x = A ? B :
    C ? D :
    E ? F : G;

// using if statement
if (A) {
    x = B
} else if (C) {
    x = D
} else if (E) {
    x = F
} else {
    x = G
}
```

No parenthesis are needed to clarify the ternary operator if adequate wrapping/indentation is used.

In contrast, `A ? (B ? C : D) : E` is a nested `if` statement, so should have parenthesis to clarify that:

```java
// single line
x = A ? B ? C : D : E;

// wrapped for readability, to show structure
x = A ? (B ? C
           : D)
      : E;

// using if statement
if (A) {
    if (B) {
        x = C
    } else {
        x = D
    }
} else
    x = E
}
```

---

Ok, end of long story. Let's look at the question code:

```java
// from question
int discount = (bill > 1000)? (qty > 11)? 10 : days > 9? 20 : 30 : 5;

// normalized to have parenthesis only around nested operators
int discount = bill > 1000 ? (qty > 11 ? 10 : (days > 9 ? 20 : 30)) : 5;

// refactored for better structure (using only tail-nesting)
int discount = bill <= 1000 ? 5 : (qty > 11 ? 10 : (days > 9 ? 20 : 30));

// wrapped for readability
int discount = bill <= 1000 ? 5 :
               qty > 11 ? 10 :
               days > 9 ? 20 : 30;

// using if statement
int discount;
if (bill <= 1000) {
    discount = 5;
} else if (qty > 11) {
    discount = 10;
} else if (days > 9) {
    discount = 20;
} else {
    discount = 30;
}
```